map.queryRenderedFeatures returns wrong polygon area on click with maplibre-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw and turf
I'm using maplibre-gl-js with the draw plugin mapbox-gl-draw. I need to calculate the area when the user create/update polygon or the user click on the polygon.
For the click event, i'm using map.queryRenderedFeatures which returns the polygon being clicked (if any), and then with turf.area i calculate the area of the 'clicked' polygon. When the user update or create a polygon I use drawControl.getAll() to calculate the area for the same polygon using the same turf.area.
The issue is that the two methods don't return the same value (different value for each use case).
Full CODE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Show drawn polygon area</title>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Use mapbox-gl-draw to draw a polygon and Turf.js to calculate its area in square meters." />
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@4.1.2/dist/maplibre-gl.css' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@4.1.2/dist/maplibre-gl.js'></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        html, body, #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .calculation-box {
        width: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        left: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/turf@3.0.14/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw@1.4.3/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.js"></script>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://www.unpkg.com/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw@1.4.3/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css"
    type="text/css"
/>
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="calculation-box">
    <p>Draw a polygon using the draw tools.</p>
    <div id="calculated-area"></div>
    <div id="calculated-area-from-click"></div>
</div>

<script>
    MapboxDraw.constants.classes.CONTROL_BASE  = 'maplibregl-ctrl';
    MapboxDraw.constants.classes.CONTROL_PREFIX = 'maplibregl-ctrl-';
    MapboxDraw.constants.classes.CONTROL_GROUP = 'maplibregl-ctrl-group';

    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style:
            'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/style.json?key=get_your_own_OpIi9ZULNHzrESv6T2vL', //hosted style id
        center: [-91.874, 42.76], // starting position
        zoom: 12 // starting zoom
    });

    const draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
        }
    });
    map.addControl(draw);

    map.on('draw.create', updateArea);
    map.on('draw.delete', updateArea);
    map.on('draw.update', updateArea);
    map.on('click', (e) => {
    // get draw controls polygons ids 
    let ids = draw.getSelectedIds();
    // select clicked features 
    let clicked = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point); 
    // filter only polygon drawn 
    let drawEntries = clicked.filter((_e) => {
     return ids.indexOf(_e.properties.id) > -1;
    });
    
    if (drawEntries.length){
        console.log('map direct click', drawEntries[0].geometry.coordinates);
        let area = turf.area(turf.polygon((drawEntries[0].geometry.coordinates))) ;
        let __area = turf.area(drawEntries[0]) ;
        console.log(area);
        console.log(__area);
        let answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area-from-click');
        answer.innerHTML =
          `<p>Using queryRenderedFeatures(e.point) : </br>
                  with turf.polygon
                  <strong>${
        area
        }</strong></p><p>square meters</p></br>
                  without turf.polygon <p><strong>
                  ${
            __area
         }
        </strong></p>`;
        updateArea(e);
      }
    })

    function updateArea(e) {
        const data = draw.getAll();
        let answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');
        if (data.features.length > 0) {
              console.log("updateArea fn", data.features[0].geometry.coordinates);
            let area = turf.area(data);
            console.log(area);
            // restrict to area to 2 decimal points
           // const roundedArea = Math.round(area * 100) / 100;
            answer.innerHTML =
                `<p><strong>${
                    area
                }</strong></p><p>square meters</p>`;
        } else {
            answer.innerHTML = '';
            if (e.type !== 'draw.delete')
                alert('Use the draw tools to draw a polygon!');
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>


jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/mtn6e9rg/
I'm using this example https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js/docs/examples/mapbox-gl-draw/ as reference
